# group the related values in one group

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-graphx, graphframes

trying to group the column values based on related records

```
partColumns = (["partnumber","colVal1","colVal2", "colVal3","colVal4","colVal5"])

partrelations = ([("part0","part1","", "","",""),
                  ("part1","","part2", "","part4",""),
                  ("part2","part3", "", "part5","part6","part7"),
                  ("part10","part11","", "","",""),
                  ("part11","part13","part21", "","",""),
                  ("part13","part21","part18", "","part20",""),
                 ])
df_part_groups = spark.createDataFrame(data=partrelations, schema = partColumns)
```

[image: Dataframe Output]

trying to get output as below -

[image: sample output]

```
edges = (df_part_groups
         .withColumnRenamed("partnumber", "src")
         .withColumnRenamed("colVal1", "dst")
        )

vertices = (edges.select("src").distinct()
            .union(edges.select("dst").distinct())
            .withColumnRenamed("src", "id"))
         
#create a graph and find all connected components
g = G.GraphFrame(vertices, edges)
cc = g.connectedComponents()

display(df_part_groups
        .join(cc.distinct(), df_part_groups.device == cc.id)
        .orderBy("component", "partnumber", "colVal1"))
```

Above is what I am trying to put together

thanks for help!!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the grouping-algorithm? Is the number of rows/column of interest here - simplest grouping would be `i < 3`.

Comment: grouping are based on relationships. like part0 is related to part1, part1 is related to part2 and part4. so part0 is indirectly related to part2 and part4 as well. similarly, part2 is also related to part3, part5, part6, part7. Thats why we can group part0,part1, part2, part3, part4, part5, part6, part7 together in one group G1.

No there is no limit on number of rows but lets just say we will not have more then 6 columns in this set.

Comment: Okay. What about your column head/titles and empty rows.

Comment: Column titles wont matter, for this very question. we can consider them like -
partnumber |  groupnumber
and we can skip the empty rows or disregard them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a simple check using set intersection to solve the problem.
(Not aware of GraphFrames :()

step 1: combine all parts in to a single array for each row

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    
df_part_groups1= df_part_groups.withColumn('parts', F.array('partnumber', 'colVal1', 'colVal2', 'colVal3', 'colVal4', 'colVal5')  )
```

step 2: get all_parts which is a list of lists of combined parts, since the group needs to be determined amongst various rows.

```
def clean_lists(plists):
  return [ list(filter(None, pl)) for pl in plists]

all_parts = clean_lists((df_part_groups1.groupBy(F.lit(1)).agg(F.collect_list('parts').alias('parts')).collect())[0].parts)
```

step 3: get groups data using the collected all_parts

```
def part_of_existing_group(gps, pl):
  for key in gps.keys():
    if set(gps[key]) & set(pl):
      gps[key] = list(set(gps[key] + pl))      
      return True
      return False   
      
def findGroups(plists): 
  groups = {}    
  index = 1
  for pl in plists:
    if len(groups.keys()) == 0 or (not part_of_existing_group(groups, pl)):
      groups[f'G{index}'] = pl
      index +=1
  return groups
```

Step 4: Assign groups based on the groups map that you created.

```
 groups = findGroups(all_parts)
    
    @udf
def get_group_val(part):
  for key in groups.keys():
    if part in groups[key]:
      return key
  return -1

df_part_groups2 = df_part_groups1.withColumn('part', F.explode('parts')).dropDuplicates(['part']).where(~F.col('part').like('')).select('part', 'parts').withColumn('Group', get_group_val('part'))

    df_part_groups2.show()
+------+--------------------+-----+
|  part|               parts|Group|
+------+--------------------+-----+
| part0|[part0, part1, , ...|   G1|
| part1|[part0, part1, , ...|   G1|
|part10|[part10, part11, ...|   G2|
|part11|[part10, part11, ...|   G2|
|part13|[part11, part13, ...|   G2|
|part18|[part13, part21, ...|   G2|
| part2|[part1, , part2, ...|   G1|
|part20|[part13, part21, ...|   G2|
|part21|[part11, part13, ...|   G2|
| part3|[part2, part3, , ...|   G1|
| part4|[part1, , part2, ...|   G1|
| part5|[part2, part3, , ...|   G1|
| part6|[part2, part3, , ...|   G1|
| part7|[part2, part3, , ...|   G1|
+------+--------------------+-----+
```

Comment: seems like right answer, let me test it over the weekend and I will update you accordingly. thanks again. appreciate your help

Comment: Thanks @greenie its working. I will see if I can convert this to grapeframe solution.

Comment: You are welcome! It will be great if you can post your GraphFrame solution as well.